# I tried to install awesome-typescript-loader and source-map-loader but there is an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

```
npm install awesome-typescript-loader source-map-loader
```

I tried installing awesome-typescript-loader (a TypeScript loader), and source-map-loader (for debugging source code) but I go this:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: 2ndtestseul@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.19.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     babel-loader@"8.0.4" from react-scripts@2.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!       react-scripts@"^2.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/babel-loader
npm ERR!     babel-loader@"8.0.5" from babel-preset-react-app@7.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/babel-preset-react-app
npm ERR!       babel-preset-react-app@"^7.0.0" from react-scripts@2.1.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"^2.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   16 more (css-loader, eslint-loader, file-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! source-map-loader@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@5.72.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from source-map-loader@3.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/source-map-loader
npm ERR!     source-map-loader@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\louis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\louis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-02T11_59_01_700Z-debug-0.log
```

Can someone explain why it is so?

Comment: Have you tried running the command that mentioned in error `this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps`?

Comment: Yes, but there are still errors